# Java tomcat thread memory usage limit

Tags: java, tomcat, thread-safety, out-of-memory, backend

I have a tomcat server that handle some rest API requests.
This tomcat crash due to out of memory error in one specific rest request in some input that cause to big heap size usage so that all the site crash.

I want to limit this rest request memory usage how can I do it?
I generally want to protect the tomcat from big memory usage request that crash it. How can I do it? Maybe limit somehow all the thread max heap size?

Answer (score 0):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

You're probably looking for `maxPostSize`

## EDIT

The OP clarified it's his program that's running out of memory, not the actual post.

The JVM's heap is shared, there is not a heap for each thread, so what you're asking isn't possible. You *could* possibly set an arbitrarily low stack size and have the JVM kill your thread when it reaches a certain call depth, but that's almost an assured pathway to problems because you're not guaranteed locks will be put back into valid states.

I'm guessing your code is holding quite a bit of data in memory. Maybe you can ask another question and SO can help you design your program so it uses less memory?

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's not mapPostSize, the params is only one integer but this integer cause a big execusion that take a lot of heap memory.